Using Group action of the $\langle \sigma \rangle$ on $S_p$ for $p$ is prime, show that $S_p$ is cyclically generated by transposition and $p$-cycle

Using Group action of the $\langle \sigma \rangle$ on $S_p$ for $p$ is prime, show that $S_p$ is cyclically generated by transposition and $p$-cycle.

Sorry for long title, but this question is widely asked but I have not come across an argument using the class equation.
My idea is to consider the group action of the subgroup of any transposition to show that the action must be transitive.
Since the indices of the non-trivial representatives of the group action must divide p! and also sum to p!.
It is impossible (why?), so the index is 1
Hence the action is transitive, take an arbitrary p-cycle , then there exist another t-cycle that can be generated which is distinct from either....
But how to guarantee that the whole $S_p$ is generated ?
Thanks

What do you mean by "cyclically generated?" What is the "subgroup of a transposition" and the "group action of" it? This is all very unclear. Can you be more specific about which group action you are actually talking about?

Hi, sorry for unclear question. What I meant was take any transposition of $S_p$ then consider the cyclic group generated by it. This is ofc a subgroup of $S_p$ now consider the group action of left multiplication (left composition) on $S_p$, we show that this action is transitive. We see this through the class equation. Clearly no one in $S_p$ gets fixed by this action. So  the class equation reduces to the sum of the orbits. Clear that this indices (the summands) are > 1. Clear also that they divide p! (by lagrange) . Now I propose a lemma : there can only be 1 unique summand that is p!.

then I think my argument breaks down... the lemma is False?

So you act on $S_p$ with a cyclic group of order 2? This action is (clearly) not transitive - every orbit has at most (in this case exactly) size 2.
